# SharePoint User Specific Key Value settings

Tags: user

I need to create functionality to save user specific data like bookmark, favorites etc.

I want to know about the best approach I can take to save the user specific data so that logged in user can see their settings like we can use Property Bags to store site/web specific data.

Comment: Steve, do I need to transfer this question to SharePoint.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @ashish.chotalia we will vote close this one and you re-post it on sharepoint, on another note im not too sure you will need any custom code/state bag at all for what youre after, it just sounds like a list to me

Answer (score 1):

You can create a user profile property and store the information in the field.

Here's a couple articles on how to interact with user profile service and properties...

http://iedaddy.com/2010/06/sharepoint-2010-updating-user-profile-properties-with-powershell/

http://iedaddy.com/2012/03/sharepoint-2010sql-view-to-get-user-profile-property-bag-values/

Answer (score 0):

You could save these settings to a database if that is an option and you have the resources.

An easier way could be just to save the data to xml files, one for each user. I have done this before.

regards,
KS