# XML files to store user information or simpler solution?

Tags: 2010, workflow, infopath, xml

We are assigning users (by group or individually) specific documents to read. I am looking to store user information such as email (the users are windows authenticated), groups that they belong, and assigned and completed assignments. Is there a recommended way of doing this? I was planning to use task lists and sort, but my need of assigning one document to many people (this error: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/b748bb03-4881-4aa5-9c87-bd4558b9201c/unable-to-sort-task-lists-by-assigned-to-column) has been fruitless.  The end goal is to check to see which users have completed which documents (a report for management), and to be able to remind users to complete assignments.

Are there any non-database ways of storing this information, also allowing to query? I would rather not use javascript, but I am open to suggestions including it.  The suggestion on this similar question ([SharePoint User Specific Key Value settings](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/45908/sharepoint-user-specific-key-value-settings)) was to store in XML files. Would you store the XML files per user and in a group-specific or general library? And would the files be searchable and sortable by user as well as by assignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a csv file and powershell (you can use each column, etc.) can work ? I think it works like the xml files you want. You can parse the csv file and search things you need, you can also sort it, etc...

Apologies if it's useless answer, just trying :)

Nico.